# How to run flutter app on a real device without having to install the sdk on your phone evrytime

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I use my mobile device to run my flutter applications. I know all about the hot reload but I'm so tired of having to wait every time I connect back to my phone again maybe the next day and then the app has to be re installed and the gradle task assembler has to be built again. Please I want to ask if there is a way to reconnect easily and a way for the apps to run easily again any time I want to work on a project again after a while.

Comment: Not sure, if your machine is slow but generally speaking flutter builds at least half of the time native android takes. So that's about it. The code would usually take couple of minutes to build the app and to run it on a device.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of alternatives to building the APK and installing it on a physical device:

### Use an emulated android device

You can use an android emulator. The easiest way to set that up is probably the graphical interface in Android Studio (see https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds), but you can also use `flutter emulators --create [--name <Name>]` to create a new virtual device. Then use the button in the bottom right of VS Code to select that device, before launching the debugger.

[image: Flutter Device Selection Button]
[image: Flutter Device Selection Menu]

### Build for desktop

Depending on the dependencies of your app, you could try building the app for the platform you're developing on (Windows, Linux, or macOS). This has the same visual result as an Android app, but does not need an emulator or physical device. The rendering engine is the same (Skia) on all platforms. The obvious downside is that some plugins may not be available for desktop.

See https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/desktop on how to set that up.